# discord.js sending multiple messages not wanted

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have a bot that shows wait times for a theme park, but when requested it sends one message for each ride, and I would like to know if it is possible to send all of the rides in one message. Here is the code:

```
message.channel.send('**NOTE:** 0min wait means the ride is **closed**.')
        IoA.GetWaitTimes().then(function(rides) {
            for(var i=0, ride; ride=rides[i++];) {
                const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setTitle('Wait Times for IoA')
                .setColor(0x00AE86)
                .setThumbnail('https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41Dz-pJ5AtL.jpg')
                .addField(ride.name, ride.waitTime + "min wait")
                message.channel.send(embed);
            }
        }, console.error);  
        return
```

Comment: Currently, it looks like you are creating multiple embeds because of your loop for every ride. You need to only add more fields to the current embed so that is what you want to be looping over and generating.  You can either do multiple .addField or as in this link use an object and just pass a fields array. This link should help you. https://anidiots.guide/first-bot/using-embeds-in-messages . Unfortunately I can't run the code now and give exact steps so hope this comment puts you on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push the waiting time on an array, and at the end send a unique message with all the args of the array.

```js
message.channel.send('**NOTE:** 0min wait means the ride is **closed**.')
        IoA.GetWaitTimes().then(function(rides) {
            let tosend = []
            for(let i=0, ride; ride=rides[i++];) {
                tosend.push(`**${ride.name}**\n ${ride.waitTime} min wait`)
            }
            message.channel.send("**__Wait time for IoA__**\n\n" + tosend.join('\n'))
        }, console.error);  
        return
```